# New refrigerator installation - compressor clanks during leveling and moving

Tags: refrigerator, compressor

We just bought a new Whirlpool refrigerator (Model #WRT311FZDZ). While the delivery man was leveling it there was a fairly loud metallic clank. He said it was the compressor. It was not plugged in and running yet. We can reproduce the clank by rocking the fridge back and forth while the refrigerator is off. It has not clanked while the refrigerator is running.

Does this indicate there might be trouble with the compressor later on? We are still in the return window. Someone is coming out to look at it.

Comment: Has it reached temperature (32 - 40 in refrigerator, 0 - 10 in freezer) and then maintained temperature?

Comment: Stop rocking the fridge. It should have been left for 6-24 hours after moving before being switched on. Jostling it needlessly increases the odds of compressor oil not being where it belongs. The clank isn't concerning, but "reproducing the clank" is.

Comment: Today on the recommended (not the coldest) setting it was 14 in the freezer and 39 in the refrigerator

Comment: aim for 0 °F for the freezer. When our freezer reaches 0 °F, the refrigerator thermometer (external device with inside sensor) shows 32 °F but nothing inside freezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compressor is mounted on quite flexible pads which have a surprisingly wide range of movement. This is primarily to keep transmissive noise to a minimum, but also damps the vibration of the compressor.

What you heard while the machine was not running is the entire assembly moving within those mounts until a hard stop was reached. It is not a sign of failure or concern.

It's not likely to be a problem if you move the refrigerator while running and hear the clunk. Most machines are on wheels, but such an abrupt movement to cause a clank would be more detrimental to the contents than to the compressor!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helped put our minds at ease.